# HPC job studies and hardware utilization report

Tags: cloud, mesos, hpc, slurm

I am struggling to find a comprehensive report about a general HPC cluster's average hardware utilization. There are various data-sets available from Google, or Facebook about their cloud's hardware utilization, but are there any similar report/data-set that I can cite or look into from a HPC center.

My focus is to see how dynamic and long tailed jobs would suffer if they run through coarse grain resource managers like SLURM, or Torque. I am aware that both these resource managers support fine grained execution but they do not provide as comprehensive API as resource managers like Mesos, or Yarn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not many HPC centres publish detailed, public reports of their usage. The exception has generally been the UK national HPC facilities which provide a huge amount of data on their historical use.

The current service, ARCHER, publishes monthly and quarterly data (including usage) from 2014 to current date at:

http://www.archer.ac.uk/about-archer/reports/

The previous service, HECToR has similar data available from 2007-2014 at:

http://www.hector.ac.uk/about-us/reports/

and the service before that, HPCx, has data from 2002-2010:

http://www.hpcx.ac.uk/projects/reports/

This should give you around 15 years worth of data to examine!

Comment: thank you. they are enough to start playing with. I only see it in Hector data set that they have some showing of system utilization. It looks really sad that for scientific clusters we see only percentage of allocation as utilization of the job and not the real hardware utilization.

Comment: Is there a report [by any chance] about cpu utilization of jobs by reading hardware performance counters (cluster wide)?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, HPC strives to reach the maximum utilisation. Keeping resources busy, queues full with jobs, maintaining a healthy backlog. Resoruce/data centre usage, That will depend on the type of workload. Is it memory or compute, or IO intensive. As in anything else, there will be a tradeoff in building the HPC cluster/environment. So in general not every resource, or the cluster as a whole will be fully utilised. There are rooms of improvements. You are right about the comparison of Mesos to traditional HPC schedulers. Mesos is two levels scheduler. It's more holistic, but that does not stop one from using it with Slurm or directly with ad-hoc mpi. That is one reason why I am asking the same question as you to make the HPC data centre more adaptive to the different workloads.  [What HPC can learn from DevOps](http://walidshaari.blogspot.com/2016/12/devops-and-traditional-hpc.html), it could be using custom scripts on top of traditional schedulers "e.g routers, load sensors" one can customise and optimise the utilisation of HPC resources to some extent. Univa and IBM LSF both have some commerical proudcts that can achive this.

Comment: well I understand that utilization on HPC generally means keeping the queue busy, but I was wondering if there is study that shows actual hardware utilization like what we see in Google's papers like CPI2, or the published dataset of their cluster: https://github.com/google/cluster-data